# How to Rotate Akamai Client Credentials

Tags: rotation, akamai

I am using the LUNA API to control my GTM profile. To access the API, I had created client credentials from LUNA Control Center (Configuration > Manage APIs), which generates a set of secrets (i.e. client token, access token, client secret and unique URL). I have read in their documentation, that these are designed to be rotated. But I cannot find in the web site, where I can manually rotate it. I also tried to find if they had any API to do that, and I found (https://developer.akamai.com/api/omni/orion/reference.html), but that never works. It always gives me a "Invalid Endpoint" exception.

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't have an API to rotate the secrets pragmatically. The only way right now, is to disable the old client Credentials and create a new one, manually from LUNA Control Center.